# Why is "(eps * 0.5) + 1" not greater than "1" in computer science?

Tags: matlab, math, floating-point, precision, epsilon

I am studying Matlab, and I do not understand why `(eps * 0.5) + 1` is not greater than 1.

```
eps

ans =

     2.220446049250313e-16

fprintf('%.52f\n', eps);
0.0000000000000002220446049250313080847263336181640625
sign(eps)

ans =

     1

% 1 means that eps is >= 0
eps >= 0

ans =

  logical

   1

eps > 0

ans =

  logical

   1

eps < 0

ans =

  logical

   0

% so, now I take half of eps
my_half_eps = eps * 0.5;
my_half_eps

my_half_eps =

     1.110223024625157e-16

fprintf('%.52f\n', my_half_eps);
0.0000000000000001110223024625156540423631668090820312
sign(my_half_eps)

ans =

     1

% half eps is positive
my_half_eps >= 0

ans =

  logical

   1

my_half_eps > 0

ans =

  logical

   1

my_half_eps < 0

ans =

  logical

   0

fprintf('%.52f\n', (eps + 1));
1.0000000000000002220446049250313080847263336181640625
% correct
fprintf('%.52f\n', (my_half_eps + 1));
1.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
% WHAT ???
diary off
```

I thought `eps` is the smallest number I can add to 1. So, adding 1 to a number less than `eps` does this problem?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what the confusion is. You seem to know that `eps` is the distance between `1` and the next representable number. Why is it surprising that adding a increment _smaller_ than `eps` gives you back the same number?

Comment: Are you asking why it rounds to `1` instead of `1+eps`?

Comment: Or are you confused about the order of the operands? `my_half_eps + 1` is the same as `1 + my_half_eps`.

Comment: eps is the the next after 1 number. There is literally NOTHING between 1 and 1+eps. You just proved it to yourself

Comment: So, for example: (eps-1) doesn't exist so that's like 0 ?

Comment: Why would `eps-1` not exist? You can type this into MATLAB and see it’s not 0. If you can put into words how you interpret eps, then maybe we can help you further. I have a hard time right now seeing where your misunderstanding is.

Comment: `eps - 1` is a perfectly normal value, but `eps / (any value greater than 1)` is zero, because epsilon is the smallest value that can be represented for a given floating point representation. You can't divide it by something to get a smaller number: there are no values between zero and epsilon.

Answer (score 5):

When addition is performed, or almost any floating-point operation generally, the correctly rounded result<sup>1</sup> is as if:

- We computed the exact result using real-number arithmetic.
- That result were rounded to the nearest representable number (using whichever choice of rounding rule is in effect).

The most common rounding rule is to round to the nearest representable number and, in case of a tie, to round to the number with the even low digit.<sup>2</sup>

In the format commonly used for `double` precision, 1 is represented as:

```
+1.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002•20
```

(I have marked the last digit in bold to mark its position visually). The next representable number is

```
+1.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000012•20
```

`eps`, the so-called “machine epsilon,” is:

```
+0.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000012•20
```

So the real-number arithmetic result of adding ½ `eps` to 1 is:

```
+1.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000012•20
```

Looking at 1, the real-number result of ½ `eps` + 1, and the next representable number, we can see ½ `eps` + 1 is exactly halfway between the two representable numbers:

```
+1.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002•20
+1.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000012•20
+1.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000012•20
```

Therefore, the floating-point operation of adding ½ `eps` to 1 will produce the neighbor with the even low digit, which is 1.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000**0**<sub>2</sub>•2<sup>0</sup> = 1.

If you add ⅝ `eps` to 1, the result will be the next representable number, 1.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000**1**<sub>2</sub>•2<sup>0</sup>, because the real-number result will pass the halfway point, so the rounding will be to the next number.

### Footnote

<sup>1</sup> Difficult operations such as sine and power (exponentiation) are often implemented with less than correct rounding. And this applies to single operations only; sequences of multiple operations are generally not expected to produce a correctly rounded result, unless specifically designed and documented for that.

<sup>2</sup> In a severely limited format, with one-digit precision, it is possible both neighbors end in odd digits, as with 9•10<sup>0</sup> and 1•10<sup>1</sup>. In this case, the number with greater magnitude is used.

Comment: "both neighbors end in odd digits" --> interesting.